# Kannel - send sms on specific time

Tags: php, kannel

I have kannel installed, working like a charm. It receives sent SMS, puts the data in MySQL database, and replies. The thing is, I need to make kannel to send a SMS after time that I will specify, like 1 hour, or something. So, as an example, you send an SMS, you get a reply immediatelly, and then, after an hour, you get another. Could this be done by altering my PHP script for sending/receiving?

Comment: The problem is that the script is called only when you send an SMS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **CronJob** in the server.